# Is there an android annotation for checking the pattern of string parameter?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, annotations, pattern-matching

### Problem

I am working with Android and Kotlin and I would like to have an annotation to check if a constant `String` parameter (to a function or constructor) matches a certain pattern (regex). I read about the [Pattern Annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html), but am not sure if it applies to my problem and if it is available with Android.

So when i would have code like this

```
fun foo(@MatchesPattern("a*b") bar: String) = println(bar)
```

then

```
foo("aaaab")
```

should compile just fine, but

```
foo("bb")
```

shouldn't.

Is this possible, preferably *without* any third party libraries? If yes, how would I implement an annotation like that? (sorry, I'm not familiar with writing my own custom annotations)

#### Background

I would like to pass words with hyphen-separated syllables as params, however a word should not have more than 3 syllables (that means max. 2 hyphens per word). I'm aware I could also achieve this with default params, but I think an annotation would be a more elegant way to achieve this.

Comment: *Is this possible?* With the default library it's not, but by using a third party library which checks annotations at compile time it'd work

Comment: sure, just write your own annotation based validation, which takes a regex as param and validates whether or not the string validates against the regex

Comment: Just updated my question. How would I implement such an annotation (doesn't matter if in Java or in Kotlin)

Comment: The [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/) makes it possible to write annotation processors like the one you want.  It runs as a plugin to javac, so wouldn't immediately apply to Kotlin.  You might want to build something like its [Signature String Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#signature-checker).  You could also probably write a plugin to [Error Prone](https://errorprone.info/), which is also for Java rather than Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite as straightforward in Android as it would be otherwise because you will have to make a new project (java library) where you can put your annotation. The process looks something like this (not tested).

1. Create a new java library with android studio as a module in your project (select your project root, right click, new module). This will add a folder, for example **lib** if you don't change its default, with the class you specify, such as `MyCustomAnnotationProcessor`.
2. In your **app** directory, go to the `build.gradle` and modify it to include sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility like so:

   ```
   android {
       ...
       compileOptions {
           sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
           targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       }
   }
   ```
3. Then do almost the same thing in your **lib**'s `build.gradle` file (if not already present after rebuilding at step 2)

   ```
   apply plugin: 'java-library'

   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   }

   sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
   targetCompatibility = "1.8"
   ```
4. In the **lib** folder, create a new class for the annotation (an `@interface`) like so:

   ```
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
   @Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
   public @interface PatternMatches {
       String value() default ".*";
   }
   ```
5. Modify your annotation processor created in step 1. Note that this extends `javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor`, which is only available here because we're in a java library.

   ```
   @SupportedAnnotationTypes("your.package.PatternMatches")
   @SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_8)
   public class MyCustomAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
       private ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv;
       @Override
       public synchronized void init(ProcessingEnvironment env){
           processingEnv = env;
       }
       @Override
       public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
           Set<? extends Element> elements = roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(PatternMatches.class);
           Set<VariableElement> params = ElementFilter.fieldsIn(elements);
           for (VariableElement param : params) {
               String val = param.getConstantValue();
               String regex = param.getAnnotation(PatternMatches.class).value();
               if (!val.matches(regex)) {
                   processingEnv.getMessager().printMessage(
   Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Regex match failed", param);
               }
           }
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: +1, however, I have a remark: The line `roundEnv.getMessager()...` should be replaced by `processingEnv.getMessager()` so this compiles. Right now I'm having some trouble verifying that this works (probably configurating gradle correctly to use this annotation processor), so I'm not accepting it as correct answer yet. But I'm positive I'll get it to work so I can accept this answer.

Comment: further, the return statement should be moved outside the for loop (also to avoid compiler errors)

Comment: Yeah sorry, typo. I'll integrate your comments into the answer

Comment: I couldn't configure the annotation Processor properly for now. Despite that, I'm marking this as accepted, since this approach seems sound to me. If I can spend any more time on this issue and find a solution / correct config, I'll report back here. Thanks a lot for your help.